# TypeScript: функция высшего порядка вычисляет возвращаемый тип функции обратного вызова без его явного указания

Tags: typescript

Как typescript'у удаётся вычислить возвращаемый тип функции wrapper, если я не передаю никаких параметров-типов в дженерик?
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOmCmqA8AKgHwAUEARgFyKkCUiAvMYoQwN4BQiPiqOUEKiSV6Abk4BfTpwgIAzlD455IADZLGKDNjyl6TFgHJ0YAJ5QAFjDABzI3TGIA9M8SLUN27IVL+qjQBGJm0sXFR9BmZEQMcXNzAQAFsKPCA)

```
function wrapper<T>(cb: () => T) {
    return cb();
}

const result = wrapper(() => 'anything'); // string
const result1 = wrapper(() => 1); // number
```

Как называется этот приём и где можно об этом почитать?
Есть ли более правильный способ написания подобной функции(без ненужного дженерика)?

Comment: Так вы передаёте туда функцию, а по ней видно что она возвращает. А зачем это пытаться переписать без дженерика? Это самый прямой и простой способ.

Comment: Вообще это называется Type Inference (вывод типа) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html

Comment: @AlexeyTen Дженерик кажется лишним, потому, что я не планирую что-либо в него передавать. Но если лучшего способа выразить то, что я хочу от typescript'а нет, придётся оставить так.

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что generic не нужен?

Comment: @Grundy Typescript вычисляет возвращаемый тип сам, мне не приходиться передавать что-либо в дженерик, поэтому _если есть возможность_ от него избавиться я бы ею воспользовался

Comment: @e5738y1, не во всех случаях тип может быть вычислен автоматически, либо вычисляется не верно. Тогда generic помогают. Нужно смотреть что именно происходит в твоей функции - если там тривиальный случай, который указан в вопросе - то действительно генерик можно убрать

Comment: @Grundy Думаю, если правильно описать callback, то проблемы с автоматическим вычислением возвращаемого типа не будет, но возможно ли убрать этот дженерик, что тогда использовать вместо `T`?

Comment: «что тогда использовать вместо T» — вот-вот

Comment: Я вот не знаю даже как можно элементарную функцию `function id(x) { return x }`без дженериков написать…

Comment: @AlexeyTen, не, там же `function id(x) { return x(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Типовые параметры ("дженерики") функций могут быть выведены из переданных аргументов, что здесь и происходит. ТС сопоставляет тип аргумента функции с типом аргумента в выражении её вызова и пытается вывести тип для `<T>`. В хендбуке есть [соответствующий раздел](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#generic-functions) для ознакомления. К сожалению, у TS отсутствует официальная спецификация и нормальная документация, поэтому изучить механизм вывода типов более детально можно только в пул реквестах, ишью и исходниках на [гитхабе](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript).

"Более правильного" способа написать эту функцию не существует, без `<T>` здесь не обойтись. Вас не должно смущать что он явно не указывается при вызове. Типовой параметр позволяет подставлять типы при вызове, а не при определении, что даёт возможность выстраивать зависимости между типами в сигнатуре функции. Соответственно, если такие зависимости вам нужны, вы должны написать дженерик.

В вашем случае возвращаемый тип функции зависит от типа её аргумента.

Пример:

```
declare function f(arg: unknown): typeof arg
declare function g<T>(arg: T): typeof arg

const a = f(1)
const b = g(1)
```

Поскольку тип аргумента функции `f` задан при определении, `typeof arg` всегда будет `unknown`. Но для функции `g` он будет вычисляться каждый раз при вызове, и `typeof arg` будет возвращать выведенный тип. Дженерик здесь убрать нельзя.

Если же заменить тип возвращаемого значения в этих функция, например, на `void`, то зависимостей от типа аргумента не останется. В таком случае нам не будет важно в какой именно момент определился тип аргумента, поэтому дженерик будет излишним.

```
declare function f(arg: unknown): void
declare function g<T>(arg: T): void

f(1)
g(1)
```